# Como fazer um dropdown que importe as opções do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, dropdown

Tenho um formulário para inscrição de alunos e um para inscrição desses alunos em turmas.

Para inscrever o aluno na turma, gostaria de ter um dropdown em que eu pudesse selecionar um dos alunos cadastrados, achei que pudesse ser algo simples usando select, mas pesquisando em foruns, não entendi como fazer isso.

**O formulário para inscrever os alunos (colaboradores) nas turmas:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1 style="
                margin-top:100px;">Inscrição</h1>
            <p> </p>
            <p class="lead"></p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <form id="cadastro" method="post" action="banco/updateP.php" style="
                    text-align: left;
                    margin-top:50px;">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="FORMACAO">Formação: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="FORMACAO" name="FORMACAO" value="<?php echo $nome['NOME']?>">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="TURMA">Turma: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="TURMA" name="TURMA">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="COLABORADOR">Colaborador: </label>
                            <select  class="form-control" id="COLABORADOR" name="COLABORADOR">
                                <?php
                                    require('class/conexao.php');
                                    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM colaboradores");
                                    $sql->execute();
                                    while($ln = $sql->fetchObject()){
                                        echo '<option value="'.$ln->ID.'">'.$ln->NOME.'</option>';
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="PREVISTO">Status: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="PREVISTO" name="PREVISTO" value="Previsto">
                         </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline disabled">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="STATUS" id="STATUS" value="Realizado" disabled> Realizado
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**O banco onde estão cadastrados os alunos (colaboradores):**

```
<?php

    $nome           = $_POST['NOME'];
    $identifiant    = $_POST['IDENTIFIANT'];
    $turma          = $_POST['TURMA'];
    $status         = $_POST['STATUS'];

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'db_formacao') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO colaboradores VALUES ('$id','$nome', '$identifiant', '$turma', '$status')"; 
    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
    mysqli_close($strcon);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';

?>
```

**O banco que vai salvar o formulário que vai inscrever o aluno na turma:**

```
<?php

    $formacao       = $_POST['FORMACAO'];
    $turma          = $_POST['TURMA'];
    $colaborador    = $_POST['COLABORADOR'];
    $previsto       = $_POST['PREVISTO'];
    $status         = $_POST['STATUS'];

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'db_formacao') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO participantes VALUES ('ID','$formacao', '$turma', '$colaborador', '$previsto', '$status')"; 
    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
    mysqli_close($strcon);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';

?>
```

Esse é um sistema que já ta bem grande então coloquei só os arquivos relacionados.

Obs: Ainda não é um dropdown mas vou transformar essa input assim que souber como importar os valores do banco;
Se alguém puder mostrar ou apontar uma maneira, seria ótimo.

Comment: tenta postar o código que ja tens feito, assim é mais fácil de podermos ajudar.

Comment: Mostrar o seu código você deve, jovem padawan. Conhecer o seu contexto o desenvolvedor precisa.

Comment: Essa era até uma justificativa que eu ia dar. O cadastro, consulta, tudo ta funcionando direitinho. Só que o que eu tenho desse dropdawn é o banco e o formulário .

Comment: mostra o banco e o formulário para termos um começo

Answer (score 2):

Fazendo com select é basicamente simples. Segue um exemplo basico

```
<select>
   <?php
      $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela");
      $sql->execute();
      while($ln = $sql->fetchObject()){
         echo '<option value="'.$ln->id.'">'.$ln->nome.'</option>';
      }
   ?>
</select>
```

Agora com Ajax

```
<select id="select">

</select>

$.ajax({
   url: 'URL',
   data: 'DATA',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
      $('#select').append('<option value="'+data.id+'">'+data.nome+'</option>')
   }
})
```

Basicamente é isso.

Comment: Então, eu fiz com o seu select, o problema é que além de não aparecer as opções do banco, tudo o que tinha abaixo do select sumiu da página. Vou editar meu código pra você ver.

Comment: @MarianaFerreira A problema foi que voce usou meu codigo a `risca`, sendo que eu usei `PDO` e voce usou `MYSQLI`, vou editar meu codigo para ficar melhor

Comment: Ah, certo, tudo bem :)